# How to display the multiple select values of tableview cell in the detail text label of my previous controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an app in which I have 2 tableview controllers. In the second tableview controller, I have created an array which holds 7 values and are displayed in my tableview cell. In this tableview cell multiple row selection is possible. But I have one problem. The multiple selected value of the tableview cell should get displayed on my first tableview controller. How is this possible?

This is my second controller class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    daysarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Every Monday",@"Every Tuesday",@"Every Wednesday",@"Every Thursday",@"Every Friday",@"Every Saturday",@"Every Sunday",nil];
    temp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:daysarray,@"arrValue",nil];
    arrayValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Every Monday",@"Every Tuesday",@"Every Wednesday",@"Every Thursday",@"Every Friday",@"Every Saturday",nil];
    self.daysarray = arrayValues;
    [arrayValues release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [arrayValues count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [daysarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = ([indexPath isEqual:rowselection]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     self.rowselection = indexPath;
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [daysarray replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:@"0"];
    }
    else
    {
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [daysarray replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:@"1"];
    }
}
```

In this class, multiple rows may be selected in the table view. But now I want to display the selected value in the detail text label of the first controller depending upon a condition.

That is, if user selects (Every Monday, Every Tuesday, Every Wednesday, Every Thursday, Every Friday, Every Saturday, Every Sunday), then in the detail text it should display “every day”. If the user selects (Every Monday, Every Tuesday, Every Wednesday, Every Thursday, Every Friday) then it should display “every weekday” in the detail text. If the user selects Every Saturday & Every Sunday it should display “Every weekend”. If the user selects any random text then it should display that particular text for eg if the user selects (Every Monday,Every Wednesday,Every Friday) then it should display “Every Mo,Wed,Fri” .How is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the second view controller from first viewcontroller then you can assign the first view contoller as a delegate for first. Implement the delegate methods in the first view controller and declare the protocols in second. Once the selection is done, call the delegate method with the selected values.

SecondViewController.h should resemble like this:

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate;

@interface SecondViewController
{
id <SecondViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
} 
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate>delegate;


@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate

- (void) tableViewselected:(NSString *)value1 and:(NSString *)value2;
@end
```

The SecondViewController.m should have:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

Once rows are selected call `[delegate tableViewselected:value1 and:value2];`

Now you have to implement the method `tableViewselected:(NSString *)value1 and:(NSString *)value2;` in FirstViewController and handle it.

I think you get my point here.